# How to implement checklist based search in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a checklist of search types, which trigger api to search. For example:

1. all
2. fruits
3. vegetables

When "fruits" is checked, it calls the API with a parameter of "fruits", to get all fruits from the database.

I implemented this in Angular.js, so `ng-change` is called on each change.

My problem is that when I click "all", it makes 2 API calls. 1 for "fruit" and other for "vegetables".

How can I avoid `ng-change` making 2 calls when "all" is checked?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Questions which ask for a complete solution without showing any effort on how you have attempted to solve the problem yourself, is little thought of. Please edit in your code and walk us trough it.

Answer (score 0):

You could switch ng-change to ng-click so only the check-boxes you explicitly click call your handler function.